# Finding number of events in previous winter within group

Tags: r, date, dplyr, count, data.table

For each event, I am trying to calculate how many previous events happened in the previous winter (and the winter previous to that) within the same group (class and area).

Here is a simple dataset (my actual one has 85,000 records)

```
# creating a simple data.frame

class <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
area <-  c("a", "a","b", "a", "a","b",  "a", "a","b" )
event <- as.Date(c("2023-04-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-01-01",
                   "2021-12-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-12-01",
                   "2020-04-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-01"))

df <- data.frame(class, area, event)



str(df) # checking the structure of the data.frame

df <- df[order(class, area, event),] # sorting the order

df

df$events_in_previous_winter <- c(0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0)  # this is the desired answer

df
```

I have tried using dplyr / group_by(class, area) and mutate to count, but I can't get it to work.

I define winter as the months of 12, 1, and 2 (Dec, Jan, Feb).

I would like to know for each group (unique pairing of class and area) how many "events" occurs in the previous winter to that event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a grouped summary to create a separate `previous_winter_events` dataframe containing the number of events per winter. You can then get the number of events per *previous* winter using `dplyr::lag()`. (You can also get events two winters ago by setting `lag(x, n = 2)`, etc.) Then, merge these values back into your original dataframe using a left join.

This solution uses a `winter_year` helper column to group each December with the following January and February even though they're in different years. I use `tidyr::complete()` to add years with no events to `previous_winter_events`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

event_df <- event_df %>% 
  mutate(winter_year = year(event %m-% months(2))) %>% 
  arrange(event_class, area, event)

previous_winter_events <- event_df %>% 
  complete(event_class, area, winter_year = full_seq(winter_year, 1)) %>% 
  group_by(event_class, area, winter_year) %>% 
  summarize(
    events_this_winter = sum(month(event) %in% c(12, 1, 2)),
    .groups = "drop_last"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    events_in_previous_winter = dplyr::lag(events_this_winter, default = 0)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

event_df <- event_df %>% 
  left_join(previous_winter_events) %>% 
  select(!c(winter_year, events_this_winter)) # remove helper columns

event_df
```

Output:

```r
   event_class area      event events_in_previous_winter
1            1    a 2018-01-01                         0
2            1    a 2021-12-01                         0
3            1    a 2022-01-31                         0
4            1    a 2022-12-01                         2
5            1    a 2022-12-01                         2
6            1    a 2023-04-01                         2
7            1    b 2022-01-01                         0
8            2    a 2020-04-01                         0
9            2    a 2022-04-01                         0
10           2    b 2022-04-01                         0
11           2    b 2022-12-01                         0
```

Data:

```r
# Added a couple additional test cases from OP comments.
# Changed names of `df` and `class` because those are function names in R.
event_df <- data.frame(
  event_class = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  area = c("a", "a","a", "a","b", "a", "a","b", "a", "a","b"),
  event = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2023-04-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-01-31", 
                    "2022-01-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-12-01",
                    "2020-04-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-01"))
)
```

Comment: This is amazing. thank you. The only thing that does not work in the "real data" is the   mutate(winter_year = year(event - months(2))) %>%  as this fails if the date is the 31st of the month.  I have changed this to   mutate(winter_year = year(event - days(32))) %>%

Comment: Good point. I edited my answer to use lubridate's [`%m-%`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/mplus.html) operator, which should also solve the issue. You could also use `clock::add_months(event, 2)`, since [clock's arithmetic](https://clock.r-lib.org/reference/clock-arithmetic.html) automatically handles this situation.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong with the lag functionality, but when I run this on my large dataset, I am getting results that don't make sense to me. For instance, I have events for one group in 2018, 2011 and 2006 but it is showing events in previous winters when there are not any there. Does the lag function assume there are records for each year (and so just look at the row above/ below?) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it does assume all years are there. To address this, I've added a call to [`tidyr::complete()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) to add missing years to `previous_winter_events` for each `event_class` and `area`.

Comment: super - thanks so much for your help. I've added that in (and the month correction). It is likely that that woul work, but perhaps due to the size of my data I am getting an error: Error: Long vectors are not yet supported. Requested output size must be less than 2147483647.

Comment: How many rows are in your data? I would post that error with your data and code as a new question.

Comment: 85,000 events (so about that many rows)